# React PWA cannot open external PDF in Chrome (Android)

Tags: android, reactjs, pdf, progressive-web-apps

I have a React progressive web app which contains a link to a PDF file. The app has been added to the home screen using the Google banner (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2015/12/getting-started-pwa/pwa-general-2-@1x.jpg), so it is treated as an app, not a shortcut.

The problem is I cannot open the PDF file from the installed PWA on Android. I get an error saying: `Cannot open PDF (pdf_name.pdf cannot be opened)`.

Opening the PDF from a regular browser (desktop or mobile) works. Opening from home screen app on iOS also works.

My PWA is hosted at `app.domain.com`, while the PDF is hosted at `api.domain.com`.

The link to the PDF file looks like this:

```
<a rel="noopener" href="https://api.domain.com/pdf_name.pdf" 
   target="_blank">View PDF</a>
```

External links that go to regular pages (not files) work.

Any ideas what might prevent Chrome from being opened from within the app?

Comment: Maybe the 'scope' mentioned while 'SW" registration is preventing it to open the PDF. Usually, when we click a  normal webpage link(which is outside of SW scope) from the installed app, the link opens in a browser window.

Comment: I did not define a scope. I'm using the default service worker that's generated by create-react-app. However, I noticed that the issue reproduces only on Samsung phones. I tried the same thing on a Huawei device and it opened a prompt asking what application should open the link.

Comment: Hello @RazvanSandu Any update on this issue ? I'm experiencing the same issue. In my case, it happens on all Android devices I tested.

Comment: @AntoineROBERT, no updates unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply removing the target attribute. It opens up in a new tab anyway. For PWA's on Android, specifying a new tab with the target attribute causes an error. It seems that when you manually specify a new tab the browser reacts as if there are 2 pages to download, the pdf and an empty web page (0 kb). Oddly, the Samsung Internet Browser also does this but just downloads both. The PWA Chrome Browser errors instead.